# asymptotics of the largest real root

Tags: co.combinatorics, real-analysis, discrete-mathematics

Suppose you have a family of polynomials
$$P_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^ka_k^{(n)}x^k$$
for $n=0,1,2,\dots$.

Further assumptions:
(1) the coefficients $a_k^{(n)}$ are recursively related to the $a_j^{(n-1)}$;

(2) the roots of each $P_n(x)$ are distinct **positive** real roots.

> **QUESTION.** Are there techniques to generate an asymptotic (1st order is fine) for the largest root $\lambda_n$ of $P_n(x)$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$?

To be a bit more concrete on the "recurrence": say, 
$$a_k^{(n)}=f(k)a_k^{(n-1)}+g(n,k)a_{k-1}^{(n-1)}.$$
I hope this helps for being specific.

Comment: Depends on how the coefficients are related, but sometimes, one can find the root distribution in the limit, and thus the largest root, https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC388687/

Comment: Can you elaborate on  your statement *$a_k^{(n)}$ are recursively related to the $a_j^{(n-1)}$*? There are  infinitely many possible recursive relations and you cannot expect  to deal with all of them in the same fashion.

Comment: @Per Alexanderson: largest root is a more subtle thing then the "root distributon". By root distribution they usually understand a probablity measure (what draction of the roots lie on an interval) and it is not sensitive to a single root.

Comment: Very much depends on the exact nature of your "recurrence relation". Be more specific.